# Error opening Python Serial Port

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am attempting to run a script that a classmate has written and demonstrated to me. So I know the code is correct, it just has to do with the difference in how our machines are configured. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#import statements
import serial
import os
import time

#global constants
control_byte = '\n'
ACL_1_X_addr = ord('X')
ACL_1_Y_addr = ord('Y')
ACL_1_Z_addr = ord('Z')
GYRO_1_X_addr = ord('I')
GYRO_1_Y_addr = ord('J')
GYRO_1_Z_addr = ord('K')


#clear the screen
os.system('clear')

#initialize the serial port
s = serial.Serial()
s.port = 10
s.baudrate = 56818
s.open()
```

Everything runs up to the last line `s.open` where it gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serial_reader.py", line 25, in <module>
    s.open()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 282, in open
    self._reconfigurePort()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 311, in _reconfigurePort
    raise SerialException("Could not configure port: %s" % msg)
serial.serialutil.SerialException: Could not configure port: (5, 'Input/output error')
```

My guess is I need to change the port I am opening, but I have tried a few others without and luck. Anybody have any ideas of what is happening?

Btw, I am using Python 2.7.4

Comment: What os are you using ?

Comment: Linux, I just changed 'cls' to be 'clear' instead.. Is there anything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you need something like `s.port="/dev/ttys0"` ... the numeric port is for "COM10" style windows ports that don't have a mapping into the file system.

Your serial ports should list if you do `ls /dev/tty*`

Comment: also, I am unsure what of the tty* ports I can use.. There are tons of them so what ones are reserved and which are free?

Comment: every time I try to open that way, it says the port is already open

Comment: then maybe its already open? or thats not the right port? how many do you have in that list? only one thing can have a given port open at a time

Comment: in the command line try this `dmesg | grep tty` it will list all of your serial port. If you are using a serial to usb adapter it will look something like this `ttyUSB0'

Answer (score 5):

use `isOpen()` in place of `open()`

```
s=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0")
s.isOpen()
```

Comment: Worked for me. I am using a virtual com port.